# How to handle some specific bluetooth headset's media button event

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-mediasession

I am implementing the media button service to handle media button event of headsets(bluetooth or wired), for some specific headsets(ex: BOSE QC35, APPLE airpods), the service can't detect the event button for the first click, but can detect its next click.

For example:

let's say I want to end an internet call after clicking the media button of BOSE QC35/AirPods, the call will not end after click the media button, instead the call was routed to phone(I can also hear "call ended" voice on QC35 at the point), and when I click the media button again, the call will end.

For the same implementation, if I use Monster powerbeats2 or any wired headphones, the call will end after the first click

Here is the Code:

```
public class SampleMediaButtonService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

    private MediaSessionCompat mSession;
    private static final int POSITION = 0;
    private static final float PLAYBACK_SPEED = 1f;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initMediaSessions();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull final String clientPackageName, final int clientUid,
                                 @Nullable final Bundle rootHints) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull final String parentId,
                               @NonNull final Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {


    }

    private void initMediaSessions() {
        mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(),
                MediaButtonService.class.getSimpleName());
        mSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);
        setSessionToken(mSession.getSessionToken());

        mSession.setCallback(
                new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlay() {
                        LOG.i("Handling media button click");

                        if (//CALL IS ACTIVE) {
                            //END the call
                        } 
                    }
                }
        );

        /* Keeping the initial state as STATE_PAUSED. This will ensure when button is clicked
         * onPlay() is called.
         */
        long actions = PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY;
        PlaybackStateCompat playbackStateCompat = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(actions)
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, POSITION, PLAYBACK_SPEED)
                .build();
        mSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateCompat);
        mSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent startIntent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        if (startIntent != null) {
            // Try to handle the intent as a media button event wrapped by MediaButtonReceiver
            MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mSession, startIntent);
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSession.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent returns a key event. Try comparing the keycode you get from both of these headsets

Comment: the MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent never received any intent after the service was started, but the callback was responding except the second click on QC 35/ AirPods

Comment: Any one has  the ideas to capture the sound "call ended"